# Why is my C# application searching for Resource.dll's?

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

I have a C# application (using the legacy .NET framework, not the new .NET Core).

It handles the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event.  When I debugged the application, I saw that the event in question was called needlessly for a total of 16 times, for three separate DLLs that do not exist:

en-US\A.resources.dll x2
en\A.resources.dll x2

en-US\B.resources.dll x4
en\B.resources.dll x4

en-US\C.resources.dll x2
en\C.resources.dll x2

As you can see above, each DLL is searched for multiple times.  For each DLL (A, B and C), the public key tokens are the same.

Why are these calls being made?  I removed the event handler so that it doesn't get called, but I am interested in understanding why the runtime thinks that these resource DLLs should exist in the first place.

How can I can tell the runtime that these DLLs don't exist and should not be searched for?

Note: The application exe does not have any embedded resources.

Comment: Thats for localization reasons. You are running the application while your system is set to the en-us culture. But that is not the default culture the application was build for so it looks if there are translation for that culture in the filesystem. Thats pretty standard behavior i don't see a need to worry about that.

Comment: Also, how can I discover what culture it was built for?  This is an application that I took over, I did not develop it myself.  Thanks.

Comment: I might have stated it a bit wrong. There is one language that is embedded (its resources file) in the actually assembly. When no fitting satellite assembly is found (with a resource file fitting to the current culture like in your case) that one will be used as a fallback. I'm not sure if its anywhere stated what concrete language that is or if its just the language its used when nothing better is found whatever it is.